# Hugo: How can I display an image in my post list

Tags: image, hugo

I am trying to display an image in my post list.

In order to achieve that I added some tags in my post.md:

```
---
title: "Hello"
header_image: /images/blog/2019/water.jpg
images: /images/blog/2019/water.jpg
resources:
  src:  /images/blog/2019/water.jpg
  title: "The image I want"

---
```

Then I edited list.html and tried different things:

```
{{ define "main" }}
<div class="archive animated fadeInDown">
    <ul class="list-with-title">
      <div class="listing-title">{{.Title}}</div>
      {{ range .Pages }}
      <ul class="listing">
        <div class="listing-item">
            <div class="listing-post"><a href="{{ .Permalink }}" title="{{ .Title }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
              {{ with .Resources.ByType "image" }}
                <div class="Image">
                {{ range . }}
                    <img src="{{ .RelPermalink }}">
                {{ end }}
                </div>
              {{ end }}
{{ $.Param "header_image" }}
                --  {{ range .Page.Resources }}
                  THERE IS ONE ITEM => NOT WORKING
                    {{ end }} <<
              <div class="post-time"><span class="date">{{.Date.Format "Jan 2" }}</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </ul>
    {{ end }}
  </div>
{{ end }}
```

But when I try to display Resources, I always get [] (nothing)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your `{{ $.Param "header_image" }}` is working, either.

The way to access your custom, non-standard variables on pages, as well as sites, is through the `.Params` object, e.g. `.Params.header_image`. Note the small letter at the beginning, as opposed to capital letters for built-in params.

[Page-level params on the Hugo Docs](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/#page-level-params)

### Custom page params

To access

```yaml
---
header_image: /images/blog/2019/water.jpg
---
```

you can use this in your page template.

```
{{ .Params.header_image }}
```

### Resources

[Page resources on Hugo Docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/#readout)

It seems that `resources` is actually an array of objects, and with `yaml`, you should actually have something like this (note the dash):

```
resources:
- src:  /images/blog/2019/water.jpg
  title: "The image I want"
```

Also mind that this feature seems to only be available only for page bundles

### Debugging

You can use [`{{ printf "%#v" .Resources }}` for debugging](https://gohugo.io/templates/template-debugging/#what-variables-are-available-in-this-context).